# sizeof operator returns 1bytes for VOID operator

Tags: c++, operators, sizeof

I was looking over the sizeof operator in C++. I came across an unexpected semantic error. I had read that void data types has no memory size. But, here in case of my program, sizeof operator returns 1 for a void data type. How is this possible?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
     std::cout<<"Void: "<<sizeof(void)<<" bytes\n";
     return 0;
}
```

I am using CodeBlocks for writing code and my OS is Windows 10 x64.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html):

> In GNU C, addition and subtraction operations are supported on pointers to `void` and on pointers to functions. This is done by treating the size of a `void` or of a function as 1.
>
> A consequence of this is that `sizeof` is also allowed on `void` and on function types, and returns 1.
>
> The option `-Wpointer-arith` requests a warning if these extensions are used.